# How to implement a less generic std::is_constructible with decltype

Tags: c++

I'm going out on a limb here, assuming that it is possible but I'm not quite sure. Basically what I'm looking for is a way to switch at compile-time between using a default constructor or a constructor that takes one argument by reference.

i.e.

```
T* create<T>()
{
    return new T(1); // if possible
}

T* create<T>()
{
    return new T(); // fallback to here
}
```

I'm using the VS2010 compiler and it does not support `std::is_constructible` but I can use `decltype`.

I went digging in the VS2012 type_traits header and looked at the `std::is_constructible` implementation and well I got a bit turned around. I don't get it how people write code that way. The headers are the most convoluted piece of code I've ever seen. Anyway, I saw that it was using decltype and it got me think, hopefully someone with more experienced can provide me with an answer.

**After going through @ipc's answer I've settled on the following code**

```
// std::declval is not supported by VS2010
template <typename T> typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();

template <class T, class R0>
decltype(new T(declval<R0>()))
createInstance_(R0& r0, int = 0)
{
    return new T(r0);
}

template <class T, class R0>
T*
createInstance_(R0&, ...)
{
    return new T();
}
```

The above code will work but it does confuse the IntelliSense Engine, anyway I thought it was nice that you could omit the extra function by simply using a default argument. I've tested this code with VS 2010 and it compiles fine and runs as expected.

Comment: Out of curiosity looked inside <type_traits>. Maybe one of the reasons of such code is because VC2012 still doesn't support variadic templates, but they wanted STL to behave accordingly to the Standard.

Comment: Yeah, they did the same thing with `make_shared`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no VS2010 to check if it compiles there, but the following matches your example.

```
template <typename T> // if std::declval is not supported by VS10
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();

template <typename T>
decltype(new T(declval<std::string>()))
create_(std::string param, int) { return new T(param); }
template <typename T>
T * create_(std::string, ...) { return new T(); }

template <typename T>
T * create(std::string param) { return create_<T>(param, 0); }

int main()
{
  std::cout << *create<int>("a") << '\n';
  std::cout << *create<std::string>("b") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0
b
```

Comment: A very nice implementation.

Comment: Okay, but what if you need to parameterize `int` as well. I used `int` as a silly example, `int` is really a user defined type in my situation. I didn't explicitly state this in the question, I know the type, it's always the same but the funny thing here is that you're utilizing a literal in the type to make that thing work...

Comment: `error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template`

Comment: @Lol4t0 hmm, I think that actually explains some of the implementation details in VS2012 since they just shipped the CTP bits with support for that... though, I cannot use it.

Comment: I've removed the default template argument and added a parametrized int.

Comment: @Lol4t0 if function's don't support it can't we do this with classes?

Comment: And this _does_ work. @JohnLeidegren, what compiler did fail? `cl`? It works for me with `gcc4.7` and `cl 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86`

Comment: @Lol4t0 What do you mean by this does work? I'm getting an internal compiler error, what are you getting?

Comment: The `int` example appears to work but substitute `int` for a user defined type. I'm using `cl` 16.00.40219.01.

Comment: The `...`-trick only works with PODs. I made another edit to add non-pod-support.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, well, it works for me. May be your code differs. I just post my expample on [ideone](http://ideone.com/CMaJFh) (hehe it does not work there), and we merge it to answer, if it is correct. (declval does not work)

Comment: This code works for me. Though, I don't understand how one takes precedence over the other. Basically, why is it that this works?

Comment: The trick is that `int` takes precedence over `...` since it is a better match to `0` (or `7` or whatever). Thanks to SFINAE, the first overload is only available if a constructor with one argument exists. Otherwise the second overload is the only possibility, so it is chosen.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks @ipc I understand now. I don't fully understand though why declval is needed, why simply just `std::string()` won't suffice.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, because your type (that is `std::string`) can be not default constructible. Still, how does it work for you? I get an error with `cl`.

Comment: @Lol4t0 I updated my question with a revised answer based on ipc's code.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, your code is wrong since both functions do equally match (so the overload is ambigous). This is clearly another compiler bug in VS2010.

Comment: Is it really ambigous while the `decltype` is there to make SFINAE work? Isn't that the whole point? Errors eliminates candidates... I don't have anyway of testing it on other compilers, right now.

Comment: It is not ambiguous if `decltype(new T(declval<R0>()))` fails. But if it does not fail, both candidates are valid. Anyway, if it works then just do it that way. If it breaks in a newer version of VS, then there are nicer way to achieve this.

Comment: Alright, good to know, again, thanks for the help on this one.